# Working in modal logic, if $W=\{w\}$ for a model $M=(W, R, V)$, do we have that $wRw$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, modal-logic

If our set of worlds $W$ is a singleton, that is $W=\{w\}$, can we automatically conclude that this world $w$ is accessible from itself?

Comment: No, we can't. $\,$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. **Any** relation between the worlds is acceptable as an accessibility relation ... including the empty relation (nothing sees anything). Now the empty relation does make for a rather silly logic, regardless of how many worlds there are - any statement of the form "$\Diamond\varphi$" is vacuously false at every world, and any statement of the form "$\Box\varphi$" is vacuously true at every world - but it is allowed.

That said, we're often interested only in frames satisfying some additional conditions, either explicitly graph-theoretic (e.g. "the accessibility relation is transitive") or logical (e.g. "the frame validates the sentence $p\rightarrow \Diamond p$"). In such a case a "silly" accessibility relation like the empty relation may indeed be ruled out. But we **don't** do that automatically.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks. But I'm still having a bit of trouble of seeing when/when isn't a world accessible from itself. I think I'm correct in saying that if for a propositional variable $p$ we have worlds $w_1, w_2 \in V(p)$, then $w_1Rw_2$. But in my mind following that thought would lead me to believe every relation is reflexive, which I of course know isn't the case. How do I go about determining this in arbitrary models?

Comment: @mike123abc What is "$V(p)$?" A frame is simply a set of worlds together with an accessibility relation, full stop. Any accessibility relation will do.

Comment: This is what I've been given: "V is a function assigning to each propositional variable p a set V(p) of
possible worlds." I have a model defined $M=(W, R, V)$, where each of these things has already been assigned a specific interpretation

Comment: @mike123abc Ah. Well, $V$ doesn't affect $R$ at all, and $V(p)$ - the set of worlds of $W$ at which $p$ is true - can be totally arbitrary. So no, elements of $V(p)$ need not see each other.